# Event that manages two projects in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, events, windows-forms-designer, projects-and-solutions, circular-dependency

I want to pass information from one project to another with delegates. The project is with Sockets and I wanted that an event is triggered when either the client project or the server project send a data so that the information can appear in their respective information forms. 
But I have tried to make reference between these projects and he tells me that you can't because there can be a circular dependency.

How can I share the same event in two projects and make changes in the opposite form?

Comment: sounds like they will both need to ref a shared project to me...

Comment: @JohnB Yes, these projects are inherited from the same project. Do you have any idea how to make an event managed between the two of you?

Comment: no when i said `project` i meant a class library - ie a visual-studio-project

Comment: @JohnB Ah ok. And do you know of a tutorial to make such a library and use an event? Because I'm new in C# and event programming and I'm a bit lost

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/61b832/creating-class-library-in-visual-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change your structure

**Projects**

```
Shared class library
   Shared stuff

project 1
   reference -> Shared class library

project 2
   reference -> Shared class library
```